# Ansible delete files recursively with regex

Tags: regex, shell, ansible

I have a structure:

- dir1

  - subdir1

    - **fileX_001.dat**
    - fileX_2001.dat
    - **fileX_002.dat**
    - fileX_2002.dat
    - **fileY_001.dat**
    - fileY_2001.dat
    - ...
  - subdir2

    - **fileX_001.dat**
    - fileX_2001.dat
    - **fileX_002.dat**
    - fileX_2002.dat
  - ...

From the dir1, I want to delete recursively all the files that matches regular expression: `.*?_(?!2)[0-9]{2,}\.(dat|DAT)` (anything at the beginning, not followed by 2, followed by at least 2 digits and ended by .dat/.DAT). The files that should match and be deleted are bold.

I tried:

```
- name: delete files
  shell: 'ls -R | grep -P ".*?_(?!2)[0-9]{2,}\.(dat|DAT)" | xargs -d"\n" rm'
  args:
    chdir: 'dir1'
```

but it failed (`rm` could not find files in the directory).

I also tried:

```
file_regex: '.*?_(?!2)[0-9]{2,}\.(dat|DAT)'

- name: find files
  find:
    paths: "dir1"
    patterns: "{{ file_regex }}"
    use_regex: yes
    recurse: yes
  register: found_files

- name: delete files
  file:
    path: '{{ item.path }}'
    state: absent
  with_items: '{{ found_files.files }}'
```

but seems like no file is found. The output is:

```
13:15:30 TASK [myrole : find files]
...
13:15:30 Wednesday 30 January 2019  14:15:30 +0200 (0:00:01.008)       0:00:40.241 *****
13:15:30 ok: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] => {"changed": false, "examined": 483, "files": [], "matched": 0, "msg": ""}
13:15:30 
13:15:30 TASK [myrole : delete files]
...
13:15:30 Wednesday 30 January 2019  14:15:30 +0200 (0:00:00.350)       0:00:40.592 ***** 
13:15:30
```

Comment: have you tested whether the shell command you used in ansible actually works in shell ? Is the regex correct ?

Comment: yes, regex is correct, and no, the shell failed with same error, which was expected, as I found out later. I managed to do it with `shell: 'find . -type f | grep -P ".*?_(?!2)[0-9]{2,}\.(dat|DAT)" | xargs -d"\n" rm'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`patterns` argument is of `list` type. If Ansible detects a string, it is converted to list using comma as separator. So you end up with two patterns:

```
        "patterns": [
            ".*?_(?!2)[0-9]{2",
            "}\\.(dat|DAT)"
        ],
```

To overcome this, pass your pattern as a list:

```
- name: find files
  find:
    paths: "dir1"
    patterns:
      - "{{ file_regex }}"
    use_regex: yes
    recurse: yes
  register: found_files
```

Comment: I tried that but it failed with:
`14:52:54 TASK [my role : find files]
...
14:52:54 Thursday 31 January 2019  15:52:54 +0200 (0:00:00.026)       0:00:38.925 ****** 
14:52:54 fatal: [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'files'"}`

Comment: Not possible. My code for task `find files` does not refer attribute `files` anywhere. Please inspect your code.

Comment: Sorry I did not mention it. It failed on the second task from the original post, not on your solution.

Comment: Not possible. Registered result of `find` does *always* have `files` attribute: either empty list or list of found files.

Comment: You are right again. I found out that the issue was in the different place. I have the 2 tasks in a block with condition. I did not mention it because I thought it is unrelated. But when the first task was skipped, variable was registered anyway and it did not have 'files'  attribute in the second task.

Answer (score 0):

As we noticed there are some challenges with regex, delete and copy module. So we can try with shell or command module as given.

```
  - name:  Delete all tar files from /var/log/
    become: true
    command_warnings=false
    command: "rm -f /var/log/*.tar”
```